# Can my Android Studio project corrupt if I change a char to NON-ASCII char in android:label

Tags: android, android-studio

I just can't build an APK and I can't figure out the reasons. Earlier I changed the string value of `android:label` in `AndroidManifest.xml` from `Lapo` to `Lapó`. Is it possible that it corrupted my whole project? (path to assets) Unfortunately `ó` is a non-ascii char, so I think it can be the problem. Possibly could somebody confirm that I'm right or it should work with this modification?

Comment: Does it build if you switch back to Lapo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the app might not work if you're using non-ascii characters, but this is probably a Lint error so you can just disable that error.

But if you're looking for a good practice, you should add this string to your language's `values` folder and you can just add `translatable="false"` if you don't want to enforce its translation.

```
<string name="lapo" translatable="false"> Lapó </string>
```

Comment: I could build it now without editing the strings.xml and only edited the strings.xml for the language which uses it, so the english uses just `Lapo` do you think it is a right solution?